# Не приходят данные через AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

есть скрипт который меняет значение рейтинга в базе данных.
Отдельно скрипт работает верно, если указать прямо в нем нужные данные, но в связке с скриптом на JavaSсript не работает, я так понимаю что данные просто не передаются.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".my_rating", function(){
        var rating_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var old_rating = $(this).text();
        $(this).replaceWith('<input ENGINE="text" class="edit_rating" style="width: 40px; height: 18px; text-align: center;" value="'+old_rating+'" data-id="'+rating_id+'">');
        $(".edit_rating").select();
        return false;
    })
    $(document).on("keydown", ".edit_rating", function(event){
        var el = $(this);
        var rating_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
        var new_rating = $(this).val();
        if(event.keyCode==13){
           $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: "/engine/ajax/edit_rating.php",
               dаta: {
                   "new_rating": new_rating,
                   "eid": rating_id
               },
               dataType: 'text',
               success: function(data){
                   if(data == 1){
                       if(new_rating.length <= 1) new_rating = new_rating + ".0";
                       el.replaceWith('<a href="#" class="my_rating" data-id="'+rating_id+'">'+new_rating+'</a>');
                   }
                   else alert(data);
               }
           });
            return false;
        }
    });
})
```

И php файл которые должен заносить данные в базу

```
<?php

define('DATALIFEENGINE', true);
define('ROOT_DIR', substr(dirname(__FILE__), 0, -12));
define('ENGINE_DIR', ROOT_DIR . '/engine');

/**
 * @var array $config
 */
include ENGINE_DIR . '/data/config.php';
require_once ENGINE_DIR . '/classes/mysql.php';
require_once ENGINE_DIR . '/data/dbconfig.php';
require_once ENGINE_DIR . '/modules/functions.php';

dle_session();

if(!empty($_POST["new_rating"]) && !empty($_POST["eid"]) && ctype_digit($_POST["eid"])){

    $new_rating = trim(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST["new_rating"])));
    $news_id = trim(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST["eid"])));

    $ed = $db->query("UPDATE dle_post_extras SET rating='{$new_rating}', vote_num=1 WHERE eid ='{$news_id}'");

    echo "1";
    exit;
}
```

Не могу понять в чем тут причина, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Что в консоли разработчика в браузере?

Comment: Ошибок в консоли нет

Comment: запрос к нужному файлу видно что выполняется?

Comment: Да, запрос идет, если добавить в конце файла php код: `else {
 echo "Ошибка"; 
}`
То текст выводиться

Comment: Пробовал убирать проверку на пустые поля, код выполняется, но в базу ничего не пишется

Comment: Тогда надо понять почему не попадаешь в условия. Можно сделать `print_r($_POST)` и посмотреть что пришло.

Comment: Делал вот так в конце файла `else{
 echo "{$new_rating} - {$news_id}";
}`
Получал просто -

Comment: Ясно. Ну как сделаешь `print_r($_POST)` то поймешь что не так.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Получаю в ответ такое: `array ()`

Comment: значит объект data не доходит до пыхи. И приведение типов в пыхе посмотри https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting